# Yii: Unit test models without database server

Tags: yii

What is the preferred/correct way to perform unit tests against Yii models without having access to a database server (or other external resources)? All of the unit testing documentation I have found suggests that you have to have an active database server, but obviously that is not ideal for unit testing.

For what it is worth, here is my config/test.php and my bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/main.php'),
    array(
        'components'=>array(
            'fixture'=>array(
                'class'=>'system.test.CDbFixtureManager',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

and

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiit=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../yii-1.1.13.e9e4a0/framework/yiit.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/test.php';

require_once($yiit);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WebTestCase.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

and when I run the tests I get:

```
CDbException: CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only alternative i can think of, would be to use SQLite and supply a DB file with your unit tests. But this again has some limitations, e.g. it does not support foreign keys and some other features from a "real" DB. After all if you want to test models, you *need* some sort of DB.

Comment: I'm not really as concerned with testing that the data makes it to the database, although that is a concern. The primary thing I want to test is that the validation functions work as intended, which (ideally) should not require a database.

Comment: In this case you could just leave away the `CDbFixtureManager` and not extend from `CDbTestCase` but `CTestCase`. Create a new record, assign some attributes and call `validate()` to see if the validation works. There should no DB be required in this case.

Comment: Well, why the real DB is even needed if there's an abstraction over the database connection? The fact that fake for CDBConnection does not come built-in in the Yii package is not a blocker for writing truly isolated tests for models.

Answer (score 7):

Yii authors have a misleading name for their integration tests. They call them "unit" ones. In fact, if you need to have a connection to the DB server, it's not unit tests anymore.

If you want to test your ActiveRecords in isolation, first you should implement a fake CDbConnection which will map to some in-memory datasets (or to filesystem-based ones). Yii does not come with such a thing built-in.

After that, you just do `CActiveRecord::$db = new FakeDbConnection()` in your `bootstrap.php` and I believe you will not have to even change your existing test suite at all.

Comment: yii and testing.. I get so frustarating that everywhere there are tutorials for "unit" testing with yii, where in fact they indeed are integration tests.